# How to create or replace a procedure in Oracle from JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, procedure

How do I create or replace a procedure in JDBC?
I created the procedure in oracle, but I cannot replace the procedure from Java.

I have the following, but it does not work:

```
Statement stmt0 = conn.createStatement();
String query0 =
"CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc " +
//blah blah blah
//blah blah blah
//blah blah blah
"END; " +
". " +
"run; ";
stmt0.execute(query0);
```

From online tutorials, I see that i'm supposed to use something like:
    cstmt = conn.prepareCall (SQL);
But I haven't been able to make it work.

If you want to see more of my code, I will provide.

Comment: What's with the ".  " and "run; "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can do this.

You want to prepare and execute from jdbc, to begin with.

Second, you need to cut off your last line with the ".  " and "run; " which look like they are straight from SQL*Plus.

Note you have not put any newlines in your Java string, but that won't matter.  You seem to have added trailing spaces which is necessary.

I suggest logging or system.out.println of the string before you execute.

Don't have a DBMS right now, but it should be something like

```
String sqlproc = 
    "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FRED IS \n" +
    "BEGIN NULL; END FRED;";

System.out.println ("proc code: " + sqlproc);
Statement stmt = conn.prepareStatement (sqlproc);
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Unfortunately, I am still not having any success.  It seems java is just skipping over this section of code.  The procedure does work, I ran it in SQLPlus.  I must be leaving something out in the Java code.